# Proof about Inclusion-exclusion formula?

Tags: probability-theory

[image]

The problem requires to use the *indicate function* to prove the Inclusion-exclusion formula. But I really don't know what to do.

Anyone can help with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indicator *function* $\mathbf 1_A$ is a *random variable* that can take on values $0$ and $1$ only. As the name implies, its value is $1$ exactly when the event $A$ occurs. Since $\mathbf 1_A$ takes on value $1$ with probability $P(A)$, its _expected value is$$E[\mathbf 1_A] = 0\times (1-P(A)) + 1\times P(A) = P(A).$$

So, begin by showing that $1 - \mathbf 1_A$ is the indicator function of $A^c$, and then argue that the event $A^c$ occurs if and only if the outcome is *not* a member
of *any* of the $A_i$, that is, if and only if *each and every one* of the events $A_i^c$ occurs.  Since $\mathbf 1_{C \cap D} = \mathbf 1_C\mathbf 1_D$ (prove this!), show that 
$$\mathbf 1_{A^c} = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1_{A_i^c} 
= \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - \mathbf 1_{A_i})$$